# How to inject a column onto a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject some html and css into **youtube** to create a column on the right side which pushes everything from the site to the left. Basically I want to do something similar to what the Inspect Tool does in Chrome.

This is for a chrome extension so the code I have right now looks like:

background.js:

```
...
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'column.js'});
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: 'column.css'});  
...
```

column.js:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = 'column';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

column.css:

```css
#column {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: auto; 
}
```

But this just creates a column over-top the web page instead of pushing everything over.

Comment: If you want something like the dev tools panel, why not just use the actual dev tool panel? [Dev Tools Panel API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels).

Comment: i guess you want to draw the columns from body not from the inserted element ;)

Comment: There's no universal solution because sites may use absolute/fixed positioning for their own stuff that will overlap your column depending on the browser window width.

Comment: @wOxxOm fair enough. I have reduced the scope of the problem and will focus on youtube.com for now. I have update the description to reflect this.

Comment: @G-Cyr could you elaborate? My CSS knowledge is limited...

Answer (score 0):

What about decreasing `body` width as width of `#column`.

```
#column {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

body {
   width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: simple solution but sadly this does not work on some site like youtube.